# Grouping dates in array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array with many dates. These dates are passive. If the free time in between is more than 8 days, i need to get the opposite of these dates. I have to process these opposite dates as the number of day, start date and end date.

Example Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17-05-2020
    [1] => 18-05-2020
    [2] => 19-05-2020
    [3] => 20-05-2020
    [4] => 28-05-2020
    [5] => 29-05-2020
    [6] => 30-05-2020
    [7] => 02-06-2020
    [8] => 03-06-2020
    [9] => 10-07-2020
    [10] => 10-07-2020
    [11] => 11-07-2020
    [12] => 12-07-2020
    [13] => 13-07-2020
    [14] => 20-07-2020
    [15] => 21-07-2020
    [16] => 25-07-2020
    [17] => 26-07-2020
    [18] => 27-07-2020
)
```

The result I want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30-05-2020
            [1] => 02-06-2020
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13-07-2020
            [1] => 20-07-2020
            [2] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21-07-2020
            [1] => 25-07-2020
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far? add your code attempt in your question otherwise it seems to be ___Please write code for me free___ kind of post

Comment: I have tried many ways. There were many codes that I tried and deleted. I am very amateur in PHP language like dates. These are the last codes I have been working on

https://pastebin.com/wuNEVekS
Output: https://www.villavakti.com/emptydayblocks.php

Comment: post these code in your question by editing it

Comment: As well as format your desired output based on input data and logic. because it seems to be mismatched

Comment: I will do the logical operations later. so I didn't want to add the codes to the content. The code can be confused as there are database operations and other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is you want to get difference between dates and if difference is `>= 8` then you want those dates in separate array with days counts as well

Do like below:

```
$finalArray = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$arr){
    if(isset($array[$key+1])){

       $diff =  round((strtotime($array[$key+1]) - strtotime($arr)) / (60 * 60 * 24));

       if(($diff < 8) and ($diff > 1)){
           $finalArray[] = array(
                $arr,
                $array[$key+1],
                $diff

           );

       }
    }

}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/QBYYR

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I am grateful.
Soory for my bad english. I want `<=8` blank dates as a start_date & end_date. 

outputt will be:https://pastebin.com/fxJCv8JG

Comment: then why only those dates will come. those date will come as well which have 1,2,3... days difference as well:- https://3v4l.org/TJNRL. `<=8` means `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` all

Comment: the output I want occurs in this way. Thank you so much!

https://3v4l.org/QBYYR